# Observer not triggered for customer_register_success event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, registration

I've read through countless posts with similar issues and have made sure I didn't have the same errors.

I'm trying to use the `customer_register_success` event to trigger an observer that will fetch an image from Gravatar and save it on my server. The code for saving it to my server works fine, as I've tested it. The issue is the fact that the observer isn't being called when a customer registers.

`config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Getavatar>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Getavatar>
</modules>

<global>
  <models>
        <getavatar>
            <class>Namespace_Getavatar_Model</class>
        </getavatar>
    </models>
    <events>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <Namespace_Getavatar_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Getavatar_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setAvatar</method>
                </Namespace_Getavatar_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
</global>
```

`Observer.php`

```
class Namespace_Getavatar_Model_Observer {

public function setAvatar(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //fetching and saving avatar image

}

}
```

`Namespace_Getavatar.xml`

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Getavatar>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Namespace_Getavatar>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I'm using a username plugin, but I don't think that could interfere with the event itself?

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Dispatch event

In Magento 2, you can dispatch the event from any place: controller, model, block, data… We will create an event from controller file.

> File directory: app/code/vendor/module_name/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module_name\Controller\Index;

 class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
   public function execute()
   {
      $hello = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array('label' => Hello Magento 2));
      $this->_eventManager->dispatch('hello_magento_display', ['display' => $hello]);
      echo $hello->getDisplay();
      exit;
   }
 }
```

> ‘hello_magento_display’: event name
>
> [‘display’ => $hello]: event argument
>
> Open your browser and use link: http://yoursite.com/hellomagento
>
> Result:
>   Hello Magento 2

### Step 2: Create events.xml file to catch event

> File directory: app/code/vendor/module_name/etc/events/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="change_hello_magento_display" instance="vednor\module_name\Observer\Change" />
    </event>
 </config>
```

### Step 3: Create Observer file to catch event

> File: app/code/vendor/module_name/Observer/Change.php

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module_name\Observer;

class Change implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $displayText = $observer->getData('display');
       $displayText->setDisplay('Catch magento 2 event successfully!!!');
       return $this;
    }
}
```

**Use the link again on your browser: `http://yoursite.com/hellomagento`
Result was changed:
Catch magento 2 event successfully!!!**

Comment: Questions is about M1.